# Tangent space and gradient on subspace of Wasserstein space given by finitely supported measures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, optimal-transportation

Let $\mathcal{P}_2(M)$ be the 2-Wasserstein space over some Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ (connected, complete, and without boundary). Let $\mathcal{FP}_2(M,n)$ be the subspace of probability measures supported on $n$ points.

If $\mathcal{P}_2(M)$ can be viewed as some kind of infinite-dimensional Riemannian manifold, I'm picturing $\mathcal{FP}_2(M,n)$ as an $n\times m+(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold. For $n=1$, $\mathcal{FP}_2(M,1)$ is a smooth embedding of $M$ in $\mathcal{P}_2(M)$.

I'm interested in a characterization of the tangent spaces $T_{\mu}\mathcal{P}_2(M)$ and $T_{\mu}\mathcal{FP}_2(M)$ at $\mu\in\mathcal{FP}_2(M)$. Intuitively, there should be linear homo- and isomorphisms into the fibers of $T\Gamma^{(n)}(M)$ times $\Delta_{n-1}$, where $\Gamma^{(n)}(M)$ is the $n$-point configuration space of $M$ and $\Delta_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-dimensional unit simplex. I'd like to see this directly from the characterization

$T_{\mu}(\mathcal{P}_2(M))=\overline{\{\nabla\varphi:\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(M)\}}^{L_{\mu}^2}, \quad \mu\in\mathcal{P}_2(M)$,

where $L_{\mu}^2$ is the space of vector fields $v$ on $M$ such that $\int_M g(v,v) d\mu<\infty.$ The latter description in terms of gradient fields has a nice interpretation if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous but a bit tricky to work with when $\mu$ is finitely supported.

Also, is there a nice description of the gradient of a function $F:\mathcal{P}_2(M)\to\mathbb{R}$ at $\mu\in\mathcal{FP}_2(M,n)$?

(The same questions could be asked about $\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{p_i}|\;p_i\in M,i=1,...,n,p_i\neq p_j\}$, the subspace of probability measures supported on $n$ points with equal weights.)

Has such a description been studied? Are there some suggestions for literature? Has anyone also studied how to project gradient flows on the Wasserstein space onto the subspace of finitely supported measures?

Comment: So just as a quick heads up, your dimension count on $\mathcal{FP}_2(M,n)$ cannot be right when $n>1$. Given $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in M$, there is an $n-1$-dimensional simplex of probability measures supported on $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. Therefore, the dimension count should be $n \times m +(n-1)$, to account for this. I'm not sure of the structure of the tangent space, but I'll post an answer if I have any ideas.

Comment: You are of course right. I was thinking of the equal-weight case when I first wrote the paragraph and later extended it. I will edit my question to correct this.

Comment: I presume when you say "supported on $n$ points" you mean "at most $n$ points"?  Otherwise your space is incomplete.

Comment: I'm not sure which one is the right (most convenient) definition. At any rate, I'm most interested in the tangent structure at a point where all the $n$ masses are non-zero. Would completeness (I'm assuming you mean metric completeness) have any bearing on this?

Comment: I think the characterization that you seem to cite and given in chapter 8 of the book on gradient flows by Ambrosio-Gigli-Savaré may be wrong. The reason is that it seems to me that for the family of measures $\mu_t=t\delta_0+(1-t)\delta_1$, $t\in[0,1]$, which seems to be Wasserstein absolutely continuous, the derivative of the family cannot be understood as a continuous flow by a vector field.

Comment: @Zatrapilla. Do you mean that my way of citing it is wrong, or the book is wrong?

Comment: That the book is wrong. But I hope not. Maybe you see a mistake in the example I propose?

Comment: I‘m also not able to find a suitable vector field. I think that under stronger conditions (smooth density with spectral gap) the existence of a vector field follows from standard results on the Poisson equation, but wasn‘t the point of Otto calculus that it can deal with general measures?

Comment: I guess I'll post this as a separate question.

Comment: Good idea! Please link it here.

Comment: Here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331289/how-does-otto-theory-work-in-this-example-of-wasserstein-a-c-curve-of-probabili

Comment: Let me jump in here: as in Zatrapilla's question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331289/how-does-otto-theory-work-in-this-example-of-wasserstein-a-c-curve-of-probabili the above curve of measures is not absolutely continuou, see my answer there.

Comment: Also, if $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\delta_{p_i}$ is finitely supported then the tangent space is not really tricky. It is easy to see that the above completion takes the canonical form $T_\mu(P_2(M))\equiv \oplus_{i=1}^N T_{p_i}M$ (product of the tangent spaces at each of the atoms)

Comment: @leo, thanks for your interest. I have now understood that the tangent vectors for changing the weights are 'infinitely long' in Otto's metric (since mass has to be teleported between locations of the atoms), as the example in the linked question by Zatrapilla shows. As for the tangent vectors for changing the positions of the atoms, I have already worked out the (riemannian) direct sum structure. If you want to post an answer, feel free. Otherwise, I will add my own answer later.

Comment: @Surace: my pleasure. I really like your description of "vectors for changing the weights being infinitely long", I've never thought of it like that before and I'll keep the picture in mind. But the point is that optimal transport is really built upon conservation of mass, even infinitesimally speaking, so that "changing the weights" can only happen via transport. There is a recent theory of "unbalanced optimal transport" that allows for local mass creation/destruction, but that's a whole different story.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Hello, I just stumbled upon this question, interested in the same thing. I couldn't figure out how you got the direct sum formula you have here, so I was wondering if you could provide more details.

Comment: @Kaira: I suggest you work it out int the simple case $M=\mathbb R^d$ and $n=1$ with $\mu=\delta_0$. Indeed, in this simple case it is clear that a sequence $\xi_n\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^d;\mathbb R^d)$ converges to $\xi$ in $L^2(\mu)$ iff $\xi_n(0)\to\xi(0)$. Then observe that one can always prescribe the derivative $\nabla\phi(0)=\xi(0)$ for some $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^d)$. The case of arbitrary $M$ and $\mu$ finitely atomic easily follows.

Comment: To be more specific: if $\mu=\sum a_i\delta_{p_i}$ my claim means that the tangent space $T_\mu P_2(M)=\oplus T_{p_i}M$ is endowed witht the scalar product $<\xi,\xi'>_\mu=\sum a_i g_{p_i}(\xi(p_i),\xi'(p_i))$, where $g_p(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Riemannian metric at $p_i\in M$ and $\xi,\xi'$ can unambiguously be evaluated at $p_i$ since they are defined $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Comment: As in my previous comment, the point is that the finite collection of tangent vectors $\xi(p_i)\in T_{p_i}$ can be obtainved as $L^2$ limits of gradients $\nabla\phi(p_i)$, which can be prescribed at all the $p_i$'s independently of each other (simple localization argument)